# Data Augmentation multi target regression

Tags: neural-network, regression, data-augmentation

I am dealing with multi target regression (strongly non-linear) problems.
I am facing them using ANNs. To train them I have to generate a database that requires computationally expensive and time-consuming simulations. The database generally has n rows =~ 1000 (each row is a simulation), 15 < n parameters (x) < 30 and 10 < n targets (y) < 25.

I tried some dimensionality reduction techniques (e.g. PCA) but they did not lead to any satisfactory result.

I'd like to know if there are any data augmentation methods to reduce the number of simulations I have to do.
Any thought or advice is welcome.

---

**Edit 1:**

1. I tried variational autoencoder, but they did not perform well. Should I try GAN?
2. I thought to use kNN but they are useless with high dimensional data. Are there any kNN improvements (or something similar) I could try?